# Can't Use Multer Properly In A Controller (Node/Express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm having an issue with file uploading with Multer and unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with Multer.
In this project, I'm trying to structure things such that routes call functions (controllers) which run commands, for example creating a product etc.

I'm pretty sure I set up Multer correctly, however when I try to req.file.filename in the controller it returns an undefined.

This is my setup (currently Multer is a helper function, I'm going to move it to middleware after as this is incorrect).

**File Storage Helper Func**

```
const multer = require("multer");

//SET Storage
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const fileName = file.originalname.replace(" ", "-");
    cb(null, fileName + "-" + Date.now());
  },
});
const uploadOptions = multer({ storage });

module.exports = { uploadOptions };
```

**Product Router**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

//@Helpers
const { uploadOptions } = require("./../../Helpers/FileStorage.helper");

//@Categories
const {
  getProducts,
  postProduct
} = require("./../../Controllers/Products/product.controller");

//GET ALL Products + ADD NEW Product
router
  .get("/", getProducts)
  .post("/", uploadOptions.single("image"), postProduct);
```

**And finally, the post product controller:**

```
//POST A New Product
const postProduct = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const category = await Categories.findOne(req.body.category);
  if (!category) return res.status(400).send("Category is invalid, try again!");


  const fileName = req.file.filename;
  const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}/public/upload/`;

  const product = new Product({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    richDescription: req.body.richDescription,
    image: `${basePath}${fileName}`,
    brand: req.body.brand,
    price: req.body.price,
    category,
    countInStock: req.body.countInStock,
    rating: req.body.rating,
    numReviews: req.body.numReviews,
    isFeatured: req.body.isFeatured,
  });
  const productList = await Product.findOne({ name: product.name });
  if (productList != null) {
    return res.status(404).send("Product already exists! Please try again!");
  }
  try {
    await product.save();
    res.status(200).send(product);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send("Product was not created! Error: " + e.message);
  }
});
```

I know the traditional way of doing this in routes would be the following (which works!):

```
router.post("/", uploadOptions.single("image"), async(req,res) => {
//Run function
}
```

However, as I mentioned above, I'm trying to break the route actions up into controller functions.
When console.log(req.file) it returns an undefined.

I suspect the props aren't being passed to the postProduct function which is what causes the error, but I can't figure out how to resolve this. I've been staring at this too long, perhaps it's an easy thing to resolve and I'm being stupid (highly probable).

If someone could assist me in fixing this and explain where I'm going wrong, I would be eternally grateful.

Edit: This is the ERROR: " **TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined** "

Comment: The return type of `console.log()` is `void`. That's why your function is returning `undefined`. Is the output on your console `undefined` as well?

Comment: Yes it is returning undefined too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you are parsing the form data correctly:

```
// this is for parsing json data
app.use(express.json());
// this is for parsing form data
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? OP stated he's working with file uploads (multipart/form-data), not urlencoded bodies (application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

Answer (score 1):

This statement: `return console.log(req.file)` in `postProduct` prevents the rest of the code from running and returns `void`. [Console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) always returns `void`.

If you want to just log the file and continue with the rest of the function, remove the `return` keyword: `console.log(req.file)`.

What does the console.log output in the terminal when you run the app?

Comment: Hi I did that because before I put the console.log it wouldn't continue because req.file.filename was undefined. So I wanted to see if file was being registered (which it's not). When I remove the above issue is there.

Full Error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined
"

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the post for clarity.

Comment: I see. It might have to do with `expressAsyncHandler` then. Try removing it from `postProduct` and in the routes use this instead: `.post("/", uploadOptions.single("image"), expressAsyncHandler(postProduct))`

Comment: Just to clarify, the traditional way of using multer is working with the exact same request? Then we can rule out the frontend, the file and other things.

Comment: Hey - I just tried that, sadly it didn't work :( - if it helps, here's the repo: https://github.com/GhostCrawl3r/eshop-mobapp/tree/master/MERN_APP/backend

Comment: Yes. Every time in the past (inc from the docs it shows it working on the same request).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the repo. I can't see anything that would explain the behaviour.. So you're saying that if you remove `expressAsyncHandler` it works? So this `.post("/", uploadOptions.single("image"), postProduct);` works with the current code? Could you try again?